# Why is the arrangement of $n$ things round a circular table is $(n - 1)!$ & not $n!$ ?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are $n$ seats round a table . We have to find the number of circular permutations of $n$ different men taken all at a time when clockwise & anti-clockwise orders are different.

Since this is a circular table, we have to first fix the position of one man taking the position of which relative positions of other men can be found. We can choose the 1st man in $n$ ways. Subsequently others can be chosen in $(n - 1)!$ ways . Therefore total ways $$ n\cdot(n - 1)! = n!$$ .

But my theory didn't work as my book wrote that the total number of circular arrangements is $(n - 1)!$ ways. Why is it so? What is the problem with my theory? How did the book write $(n - 1)!$ ?? Please explain me.

Comment: You might understand the question differently than the book understands. How many ways do you think there are to seat $2$ men around a circular table?

Comment: @JiK, I think $2!$, right? Really I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

But each permutation is taken as being the same as the other $n-1$ permutations which arise when you rotate it, so you have to divide by $n$ - only relative positions matter.

Alternatively, given any permutation, you can count it clockwise from person $1$ to fit in the other $n-1$ people.

Answer (score 0):

if you are seating $n$ people round a fixed table in a restaurant then there are $n!$ ways of doing it.

however in terms of eye-contact and conversation only, all the relevant data are contained in the list of who was sitting on who's right. starting with any given person there are only  $n -1$ possibile "right neighbours", then $n-2$ and so on until the penultimate person has only $1$ choice. and the information possessed by the last person chosen is redundant, since this must be the first person due to circularity of the table

Comment: Sir, can you please explain the second para of your answer? It's really urgent. I will be grateful if I get the intuition.

Comment: you might consider carefully  @Jik's question

Comment: Sir, can you tell what he did want to tell?